# Umpire Decision Review System in cricket

Tags: officiating, icc, cricket

A team has only one review remaining in the Decision Review System (DRS), and a batsman was given out Leg Before Wicket (LBW) and both batsmen were certain that the decision was in error and called for a review.

What if the Captain wanted to keep the review for when the side came to bowl and called the batsman back to the pavilion.

Will the review be cancelled?

Who takes priority in the DRS whilst batting, the Captain or the batsmen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the **batting** team - The review can be called by the batsman dismissed only. The captain has no say in this.
For the **bowling** team - The review can be called by the fielding captain only. The rest of the team can consult the captain but cannot officially call a DRS review.

In the case mentioned above, the batting captain cannot call for/cancel a review from the pavilion. It is the batsman's prerogative whether to take the review or not.

Answer (score 4):

The player review requests are allotted per innings.  So whether the batsman asks for a review does not impact the number of review requests available to the team when it fields.  The only concern is whether the following batsmen in the same innings might want to use the review.

Comment: And also if review is successful, their review count will not be reduced. :)