# Why players showing a T-signal for umpire decision review system?

Tags: cricket, officiating, terminology, trivia

While calling for the [Umpire Decision Review system](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1906/umpire-decision-review-system-in-cricket),

> The fielding team captain or the batsman being dismissed invokes the
>   challenge by signalling a "T" with the arms.- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umpire_Decision_Review_System#System).

What that signal `'T'` refers to?

Does it refer the third umpire/TV umpire?

If yes, where is it documented/stated by any cricket officials/players?

Comment: Why do umpire take both hands up to declare the ball as a Six? It's just a signal IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ICC Playing Comditions can be found here: http://www.icc-cricket.com/about/38/rules-and-regulations.

In the first document, "Standard Test Match Playing Conditions", you'll find:

> 3.2 The manner of requesting the Player Review
>
> a) The request should be made by the player making a ‘T’ sign with both
> forearms at head height.

Having seen a few such requests on television, I feel some players are not taking the "at head height" part too seriously.

Comment: so, the signal 'T' may or may not refer any term, it is an icc rule for DRS, is it?

Comment: @SportsFan I don't know how they came up with the sign. But note that the requirements of a new sign should probably be that 1) it is not something that you might accidentally do too often, 2) it would preferably not be offensive in some cultures, 3) it should be easy to perform for most people, 4) it should be unambiguous, ...